# Как убрать появление отступов в BottomSheet при замене фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout, android-bottomsheetbehavior, android-bottomsheet

Проблема следующая: имеется bottom_sheet_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="30dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При замене(или добавлении) фрагмента в коде в bottom_sheet_content:

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.bottom_sheet_content, NewBottomSheetFragment())
                            .commit()
```

Появляется вот такой отступ в BottomSheet:
[image: Появляющийся отступ]

Код фрагмента NewBottomSheetFragment:

```
class NewBottomSheetFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = ::requireParentFragment)

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_fragment_new, container, false)
        return inflatedView
    }
}
```

XML Файл этого фрагмента bottomsheet_fragment_new:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_part_new"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="@string/transitionName">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_choose_circle_default"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_confirm_order"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_address_from" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/BottomSheetText"
        android:id="@+id/et_address_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/BottomSheetText"
        android:id="@+id/et_address_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_order"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_places_choice"
        android:theme="@style/PassengerTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_address_to" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_choose_circle_default"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_place_choose_circle_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Пересмотрел много источников и по-разному попробовал исправлять это, но, увы, никакой из моих методов не принёс плодов. Поэтому прошу Вас помочь мне.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас внутри bottomSheet есть фрагмент и когда вы его вставляете появляется черный отступ? А можно код самого фрагмента и XML?

Comment: Да, Вы правильно понимаете. Добавил код фрагмента и его xml в описание вопроса.

Comment: Я могу предположить, что когда вы вставляете новый фрагмент, то он становится меньше предыдущего. А т.к. у вас размер макета стоит wrap_content то он просто оставляет пустое место (черную полосу). Попробуйте задать размер вставляемого фрагмента match_parent

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло(
Кстати, изначально FragmentContainerView для фрагмента пустой, в него с помощью транзакции помещается фрагмент

Comment: Попробуйте запустить LayoutInspector и посмотреть, что это за черный прямоугольник. Тут важно понять откуда он

Comment: Да, Вы были правы, что LayoutInsperctor поможет понять его происхождение)
Увидел, что в layout у всего bottomSheet (constraintLayout) почему-то устанавливается paddingTop = 84
Попробовал программно обнулять его после транзакции - всё равно 84 остаётся
Попробовал задать paddingTop = 500dp в разметке xml, но всё равно число 84 остаётся, и большой прямоугольник в 500dp из разметки превращается в тот, который я показывал на рисунке. В чём может быть дело? Уже попробовал поставить "false" разные атрибуты вроде clipToPadding, clipChildren - нет эффекта(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110525/discussion-between-sergei-buvaka-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Ошибка была в строке android:fitsSystemWindows = "true". Убрав её, отступ исчез. Когда разбирался, то видел инфу, что coordinatorlayout не дружит с fragmenttransactions при таком флаге, и везде добавляет такие отступы.